# aws Ec2 ubuntu - importing module with an underscore in the name

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask-sockets

i'm trying to deploy some python program on my EC2 instance.

In the code there is this line:

> from flask_sockets import Sockets

Error:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sockets'**

But flask_sockets is installed, pip freeze gives:

> Flask-Sockets==0.2.1

Importing it like

> from flask-sockets import Sockets

isn't working as well.

Anyone got an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Not nearly enough information here. How did you install it? Are you using a virtualenv? Does it work in development?

Comment: i'm not using a venv. I installed it using "pip install flask_sockets".
The version of python is 3.6. So i upgraded the instance from the standard 2.7.

On a local machine it works like a charm.

Comment: Well this is exactly why you should use a virtualenv. It sounds like you installed the library for the wrong version of python. You could try using pip3 instead but if you really want help you're going to need to explain exactly how you upgraded python and how you're starting your app.